# How to return a struct from inside an Rc?

Tags: rust

I have a struct wrapped in a `Rc` called `Data`. I want to create a function that returns the `Data` inside the `Rc`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    pub struct Data {
        pub tag: Vec<u8>,
        pub bytes: [u8; 32],
        pub length: u8,
    }

    pub struct SharedData {
        pointer: Rc<Data>,
    }

    pub fn get_data(shared: SharedData) -> Data {
        shared.pointer
    }
}
```

In this contrived example I have stripped away a lot of my surrounding code so the idea might look strange.

Comment: Instead of using `#[allow(unused)]` you could just remove the unused variables in your post ;) Please do that next time and use `rustfmt` to format your code according to the guidelines of Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, `Rc` is a [reference-counted pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html). It is used for sharing data between different sections of code without needing to have a single owner. However, this also hints at the reason your code is unable to directly return a `Data`: in order to return that, it must first find a way to satisfy the borrow checker's notion of data ownership.

The options are generally to take sole ownership of the data, or clone it. In the edited code included below, I've changed `get_data` to first get access to `Data` by dereferencing the pointer (`Rc` implements the [`Deref` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)), and then cloning the struct before returning it. Because the return type is `Data` (and not `&Data`) this means that this value is now owned by the caller. Because it was cloned, any mutations will not be visible to any code still referring to the `Rc<Data>`. Note that I needed to derive the `Clone` trait on `Data` before the `clone` method was available.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::error;
use std::error::Error;
fn main() {
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct Data {
        pub tag: Vec<u8>,
        pub bytes: [u8; 32], 
        pub length: u8,
    }

    pub struct SharedData {
        pointer: Rc<Data>,
    }

    pub fn get_data(shared: SharedData) -> Data {
        // Dereference the pointer, and then return
        // a copy of its data
        (*shared.pointer).clone()
    }

    pub fn get_data_length(shared: SharedData) -> u8 {
        // For simpler types, you can just access the fields inside
        // Data directly
        shared.pointer.length
    }
}
```

I've also included a `get_data_length` to demonstrate that individual members of the shared data can also be returned without formally cloning.

Finally, if you intend to have shared *mutable* access to data, a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) might be a more appropriate choice than an `Rc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the Rc, [`try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap) might be worth taking a look at. You can unwrap the result if you are sure that no other reference will exist.